# Git: after merge I see a new untracked file `\032\032` I can't get rid of

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I merged some changes up to Github and afterward ran `git status` and same a new untracked file:

```
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       "\032\032"
```

I've checked in the directory and there is no new file or directory there. I also tried running `rmdir` and `rm -i` but both times I get a `No such file or directory` message.

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\032` is an unprintable ASCII-range control character, [the SUB or Substitute character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character) control-Z.  You have a file that is literally named <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd><kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd>.  Git knows that attempting to display this undisplayable character will fail, so instead it prints, inside double quotes, the C-style escape sequences that would generate the characters in a C string: `\032` = octal 32 = decimal 26 = control-Z.

It's not clear how you *got* this file, but since it's "untracked", it's not in Git at all, it is merely in your work-tree.

It's also not clear how you should remove that file, since <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> is often eaten by something else long before you can give it to a "delete file" command.  If you are on a Unix-like system with a Unix-like shell (sh or bash for instance), you can use:

```
rm $'\032\032'
```

since these shells expand octal backslash sequences inside `$'...'`.

Answer (score 6):

try "git stash" to get rid of it.

Comment: 'No local changes to save' unfortunately

Comment: does it still show that untracked files when you try git status again? if it still show ,try "git clean -n" and then "git clean -f"

Comment: try "git stash --include-untracked"

Answer (score 1):

Try `Hard Reset` to the last commit -

```
$ git add .
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: "git reset --hard HEAD" to go back to last commit solved it.